# Information from arrays in c# using listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

I am using listboxes to create a small shop for a class project.
I have 3 arrays, items (stores a string for names), prices (stores a decimal for prices), pics (stores an image for the items).

http://prnt.sc/chrn6z

I have everything working EXCEPT the remove item from cart button. When it removes an item from the right listbox, it needs to subtract the price for the selected item in that list box from the totalprice variable.

My issue is, that I do not know how to get the prices array decimal for the item in the cart (right list box).
I tried this:

```
prices[lstCart.SelectedIndex]
```

I tried that, however it gave me an IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Is the cart another ListBox? If so what are you storing, item names as strings?

Comment: lhttp://hastebin.com/kenowocefe.pl @Keyur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Easier to change it here:

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string selectedProduct = lstCart.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int selectedProductIndex = Array.FindIndex(items, row => selectedProduct.Contains(row));
    if (selectedProductIndex == -1) return;
    decimal selectedProductPrice = prices[selectedProductIndex];
    totalPrice = totalPrice - selectedProductPrice;
    MessageBox.Show(totalPrice.ToString());
    lstCart.Items.Remove(lstCart.SelectedItem);
}
```

Since your selectedProduct is a string joined of item and price, it should satisfy the `Contains`. It is a bit of a messy hack, but let me know if it works.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/13bca76ae71a3ac83830e62fce96f750
That is how it works, so not sure how, the way you have it adding would help.

Comment: Edited the answer to match your scenario.

Comment: Neither worked. First, returned no information and second returned NullReference @keyur

Comment: Then add a `if (lstCart.SelectedItem == null)
{
    return;
}` before the first `string input` line. Also, how can SelectedItem return null if you're selecting an item from the listbox before running that code. Its unusual.

Comment: You cannot call `lstCart.Items.Remove(lstCart.SelectedItem);` in the beginning! Call it just before closing the function, otherwise the SelectedItem is obviously null.

Comment: `Array.FindIndex(items, row => selectedProduct.Contains(row));`
IT did work, however, can you explain what this bit does, I understand that it finds the index in array items but thats it

Comment: It iterates through the `items` array, then `row => selectedProduct.Contains(row)` is called for every item inside the array. `row => selectedProduct.Contains(row)` just checks if any value inside the items array is a substring of `selectedProduct`. Helpful links: [String.Contains Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx), [Array.Find<T> Method (T[], Predicate<T>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is just a variable, its identical to "for every string x inside `items`, var row = x;" And it iterates over every string inside one by one, assigning each value to `row`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like finding the original index of the product you selected and then use it as the index to get the corresponding price.

```
string selectedProduct = lstCart.SelectedItem.ToString();
int selectedProductIndex = Array.IndexOf(products, selectedProduct);
double selectedProductPrice = prices[selectedProductIndex];
totalPrice = totalPrice - selectedProductPrice;
```

Comment: string selectedProduct = lstCart.SelectedItem.ToString(); this returns NullReference?

Comment: lstCart is the name of your shopping cart listbox?

Comment: Yes. It is the name

Comment: How are you adding the items to the shopping cart?

Comment: @lamelemon Very obvious problem: `lstCart.Items.Remove(lstCart.SelectedItem);` at the start rather then at the end of the function. Otherwise I think your answer will work.

Comment: @keyur Yes, that was my bad, totally forgot about that when I was moving stuff around, however, the:
'int selectedProductIndex = Array.IndexOf(products, selectedProduct);'
is returning IndexOutOfRange

Comment: I think this is because the message added to the lstCart is not part of one array but two.

Comment: Try changing that line to `int selectedProductIndex = Array.FindIndex(myArray, row => row.Contains(selectedProduct));` then immediately afterwards `if (selectedProductIndex == -1) return;` since that means nothing was matched.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL http://hastebin.com/romidanule.cs Like this? Tried this and nothing happened. I am sorry, I am just learning c#. So, my knowledge is pretty limited.

Comment: Check my modified answer.